# How to style column groups

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have a large table that spans multiple horizontal screen widths on a normal display because it has many columns. These columns are grouped in column groups, which can be quite large. Now I have the problem that when looking at the values in the table, it is not directly visible in which column group a cell is because the only visual guide is in the column header. Since in my use case there are multiple column groups with similar information, it is quite hard to tell which cell belongs to which column group and/or column.

Let's say we have the following column defs:

```
var columnDefs = {
    headerName: "Sports Results 2016",
    marryChildren: true,
    children: [
        {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Total", field: "total", width: 75}
    ]
},
{
    headerName: "Sports Results 2017",
    marryChildren: true,
    children: [
        {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Total", field: "total", width: 75}
    ]
},
{
    headerName: "Sports Results 2018",
    marryChildren: true,
    children: [
        {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 75},
        {headerName: "Total", field: "total", width: 75}
    ]
};
```

Now when I look at a row at the bottom, it's kind of hard to compare the values between column groups. And it gets worse if the units differ from column to column (m, kg, sec, etc) and are only written in the header.

[Here the plunkr for the code with the resulting layout.](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/O17iHavbePgGfsff)

Now I am searching for a way to add a some styling to the column group, so there is a visual distinction within the data table between different column groups. Something like vertical lines between column groups. Like in the following picture (color red chosen for demonstration, in the end black or a similar style as in the header row would be nice):

[image: Ag grid with borders around column groups]

I tried to find a easy way to get such a layout in ag-grid, but I only found ways to add a style only to the headers or every cell in the column group. Does someone have some experience with such a situation or have an idea how to make the distinction more clear?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution that works, but uses a undocumented property of the cell object used during the cell customization. And it only works with *cellStyle* and not with *cellClass* or *cellClassRule*. ([See section Cell Styles -> cell style in Ag grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/))

Basically you can add a default column definition to the grid options that sets the cell style of each column and therefore of each cell to a function. This function paints a border on the left side of a cell, if the column of the cell is the first displayed child of it's parent.

```
var defaultColumnDefs = {
    cellStyle: (cell) => isFirstColumn(cell) ? {'border-left': '2px solid red'} : null
};

var gridOptions = {
    ...
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    defaultColDef: defaultColumnDefs
};

function inFirstColumn(cell) {
    // cell.column is not a documented property!!
    return cell.column.colId === cell.column.parent.displayedChildren[0].colId;
}
```

[Here is the updated Plnkr.](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/O17iHavbePgGfsff?preview)

Comment: Thanks! That works wonderfully for the grid's cells. Is there any way to extend this to the header as well (to have the borders extended to the headers)?

Comment: Without having tried this myself, you can check whether you can do a similar method just for the header cells, at least there is an headerClass on the ColDef. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-header-headerClass

Comment: This worked well for my use-case although it wasn't refreshing the styles on column move. The trick is to call `api.redrawRows()` on the `onColumnMoved` event - this is in the above plunker but worth mentioning. You can even wrap it so that it only redraws if the column is part of a group by checking `event.column?.getParent()`

Answer (score 1):

The demo of the solution I would do:

[updated plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/76Ue3lUaNu49Y64w)

What I did is I used the cellStyle in column definition and gave it a solid red border :

```
cellStyle: {'border-left': '5px solid red'}}
```

Or to put that together in appropriate element:

```
{
        headerName: "Sports Results 2016",
        marryChildren: true,
        children: [
            {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
            cellStyle: {'border-left': '5px solid red'}},
            {headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'},
            {headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'},
            {headerName: "Total", field: "total", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'}
        ]
    }
```

Simply do that for all the cells columns you wanna. The only difference is that there are breaks in the lines, if that does not bother you, solution conveys the message of splitting up a table at certain rows and is really simple to do.

You might also wanna to separate CSS from your cell definitions and you can do that with cellClass property in the definition.

More info on both approaches here:

[ag-grid Cell Styling](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/)

Since you told you already know how to style headers, add the same to headers if you wanna line to go from header to bottom. If you wanna full line, however, I can only think of making a really thin cell with all borders and background red to mimic the vertical line. Then you need to add that in front of every element you wanna to have the line on left side.

Maybe something like this:

```
{
        headerName: "Sports Results 2017",
        marryChildren: true,
        children: [
            {width: 1,
                cellStyle: {
                'padding': 0, background: 'red', width: '3px'}
            },
            {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'},
            {headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'},
            {headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'},
            {headerName: "Total", field: "total", width: 75, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'}
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this approach breaks on reordering the columns and I need the reordering functionality. :/
Is it possible to assign such a styling to the first child of each column group? And this dynamically, so that on reordering, the boarders are redrawn in the correct column.

Comment: I could be done but not as simple as this. The moving of the row will move the line as well since its a style of the cell. You can try the inserting a thin cell column with background and borders in red and fix it to be 1st one, without the ability to reorder maybe. Or you can change cell classes and remove/add them to certain row on reorder event

Comment: Is there a event thrown on reordering? I could not find any in the docu.

Comment: I don't know similar grid lib I use has. I have upgraded answer with a simple demo how to insert a cell simulated line. Problem is a parent with width has still some padding making it fatter, and I have not figured out how to style headers this way other than inserting a fake one.

Comment: Column moves indeed triggers an event named columnMoved (accessible through  GridOptions) -> https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/